# Angular report current route and params to any component?

Tags: angular, rxjs, url-routing

I have literally no idea why this is so hard... why we're officially not supposed to care about the route from anywhere but inside the routed component.... BUT:

I'm trying to write a service to my header (and any other component) can know the current route and params. Would be nice to know the currently loaded component as well but that's less important.

I have tried various solutions from [this thread](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11023) and the one that got me closest was a paraphrase from RoyiNamir but as you can see from the attached stackblitz, it only reports the param on page load, not on subsequent navigation despite the subscription and the presence of NavigationEnd (though I'm admittedly super green when it comes to interpreting routing events, and to rxjs as well).

I'm also unsure of how to pass the current route in the returned object along with the params.

Code:

```
import {Injectable}                              from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute, NavigationEnd, Router}   from "@angular/router";
import {Observable}                              from "rxjs";
import {first, filter, map, switchMap}           from "rxjs/operators";

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class RouteService {
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute, 
    private router: Router
  ){}
  public getActivatedRouteParameter(): Observable<any>
  {
    let params
    params = this.router.events.pipe(
      filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd),
        map((): ActivatedRoute => {
          let route = this.route;
          while (route.firstChild)
              {
                  route = route.firstChild;
              }
          return route;
        }),
        filter((route: ActivatedRoute) => route.outlet === 'primary'),
        switchMap((route: ActivatedRoute) => route.paramMap) , first()
    );
    return params;
  }
}
```

[Working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routing-service)

Comment: Have you tried [`@ngrx/router-store`](https://ngrx.io/guide/router-store)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work fine if you modify the `getActivatedRouteParameter` like this:

```js
public getActivatedRouteParameter(): Observable<any>
  {
    let params
    params = this.router.events.pipe(
      filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd),
        map((): ActivatedRoute => {
          let route = this.route;
          while (route.firstChild)
              {
                  route = route.firstChild;
              }
          return route;
        }),
        filter((route: ActivatedRoute) => route.outlet === 'primary'),
        switchMap((route: ActivatedRoute) => route.paramMap.pipe(first())) , /* first() */
        tap(console.log)
    );
    return params;
  }
```

Adding `first()` **outside** of `switchMap` it will cause the **entire stream** to complete after the first emission, which would be an empty object(since [`ActivatedRoute`'s properties are `BehaviorSubjects`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/6768fe9927ad4b9b81c5f8094c42c771d1047f56/packages/router/src/create_router_state.ts#L76-L80)):

```js
function createActivatedRoute(c: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
  return new ActivatedRoute(
      new BehaviorSubject(c.url), new BehaviorSubject(c.params), new BehaviorSubject(c.queryParams),
      new BehaviorSubject(c.fragment), new BehaviorSubject(c.data), c.outlet, c.component, c);
}
```

By adding `first()` to the `switchMap`'s inner observable, you're not getting duplicates. You'd get duplicates otherwise because, in your case, every route navigation will **use the same component**(`HomeComponent`), which means it will not be destroyed, so the `ActivatedRoute` will be the same and so will its observable properties.

This also means that the inner observable will not complete, so when the `ActivatedRoute` will be reused, it will [update its `BehaviorSubject` instances](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/6768fe9927ad4b9b81c5f8094c42c771d1047f56/packages/router/src/router_state.ts#L422).

```js
...
    if (!shallowEqual(currentSnapshot.params, nextSnapshot.params)) {
      (<any>route.params).next(nextSnapshot.params);
    }
...
```

And this happens earlier in the pipe, **before** the `NavigationEnd` event.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routing-service-tdjwtq?file=src%2Fapp%2Froute.service.ts)

Comment: Well I'll be damned. Works great. Are you able to lend a hand with the second part of the question: reporting the active route along with the params?

Comment: @jugglervr Sure, it shouldn’t change the logic too much. You could add a map operator after “first” operator. Something like: “map(params => ({params, route}))”, where route is available with the help of the closure. Also, if you want other properties(e.g queryParams, url) you could make switchMap’s inner obs fn to return something like: “merge(queryParams.first(), params.first()..).toArray()”